# Facebook Share button right align

Tags: css, facebook-sharer

I am trying to align a [FB share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) to the right in a box. The problem is the counter on the right side of the button, which makes the button wider with each character, so I can't set a proper width.

- Removing the width values from the `iframe` does not help.
- `width: auto;` does not help.
- `width: 135px;` fits nice IF the counter is 3 digits long, but leaves a margin if it's shorter.

```css
.share {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 135px;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <iframe class='share' src='https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=SOME_URL&layout=button_count&size=large&width=110&height=28' width='110' height='28' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</footer>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: @NicoHaase It does not. I am aware of the JS solution (with the CORS issue). I don't want to modify the button itself, only the outer `iframe`, which is on my side.